# Multiple animation at a time

Tags: c++, sdl

I'm making a Asteroids game but I can not get to play more than one explosion at a time. Just get to do one at a time ...

This is my code I call in the main loop:

```
for(i = 0; i < MAX_SHOTS; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < MAX_ASTEROIDS; j++) {
        if(shot[i].CheckCollision(asteroide[j])) {
            shot[i].SetPos(-100, 0);
            explosionSnd.Play();

            numAst = j;
            explosion[numExp++].Enable(true);

            if(numExp == MAX_EXPLOSIONS-1) {
                numExp = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}

for(i = 1; i < MAX_EXPLOSIONS; i++) {
    if(explosion[i].Enable()) {
        explosion[i].SetPos(asteroide[numAst].GetX(), asteroide[numAst].GetY());
        explosion[i].Draw();
        if(explosion[i].GetFrame() == 5) {
            explosion[i].Enable(false);
        }
    }
}
```

If I shot to an asteroid and after I shot to another, the animation is cut and goes to the new asteroid.

Any help?

Thank you.

Comment: doesn't look like you keep a count of how many explosions are active. So how are you creating a new explosion then? are you searching for the first 'disabled' explosion and changing it?

Comment: I'm assuming that numExp is doing that - though it just makes the assumption that there will never be more than MAX_EXPLOSIONS visible at once :)

Comment: Of course deanWombourne is right :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside your second loop, you're moving each explosion to the location of the asteroid `asteroide[numAst]` - you're playing all the explosions, just all at the same place!

You should only position the explosion once after you `Enable(true)` it, when it's created in the first loop, not each time you draw it.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, I've managed with what you said xD
In the end I removed the explosion follow the asteroid and the effect is much better